# How to make TrailRenderer work when timeScale is 0 in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use TrailRenderer when my game is paused, but since timeScale is 0 the resulting deltaTime is 0, this caused TrailRenderer to not function (the tail never dies)

I dint find any parameter to be able to manually set the update duration or call update of TrailRenderer.

Like in An Animator we have the option to make it update in "UnscaledDeltaTime", how can i do it for a TrailRenderer?

I also tried to add it manually in the decompiled Trail Renderer but it seem trail renderer code in not in C#

Comment: You should add the code around the issue, so we have something to work with. I'd say you can do many things: You can calculate the deltatime using the system time (deltatime = timestampNow - timestampLastCheck)

Comment: yes i can calculate that but there is no varible to which i can assign it to have the desired effect.

Answer (score -2):

It seems [unscaledTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledTime.html) is what you might be looking for.

> Unlike time this value is not affected by timeScale.

Comment: There is no option for unscaled time in TrailRenderer